# Type safety warning in JSP page

Tags: jsp, servlets, arraylist

In a `ServletContextListener`, I set an attribute like this:

```
ArrayList<String> prefs = new ArrayList<String>();
...
...
sc.setAttribute("user-preferences", prefs);
```

I try to use the attribute in a JSP page like this:

```
ArrayList<String> prefs = (ArrayList<String>) config.getServletContext().getAttribute("user-preferences");
```

I get the following warning:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList

Can someone please tell me why I get this warning?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a question in your source code, Why don't you use application.getAttribute() to get the attribute from servletContext?

Comment: @Naved: Yes, thanks. I should have done that.

Comment: Why don't you just use EL? It's available by `${prefs}` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This warning is because `ServletContext.getAttribute()` does not support generics and the method signature of this method says the return object is `Object`. But, you are type casting it to `ArrayList<String>`.

[ServletContext.getAttribute() API Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)

It's a standard Java warning, indicating that you are casting a non-generic type (Object) to a generic type (ArrayList).

In Java you can remove the warning by using an unchecked annotation.

[Unchecked Warning Turtorial](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ001)

Comment: Thanks. I have replaced the `ArrayList<String>` with a `String[]`. No warning now. Is this a good practice?

Comment: Writing Java code in a JSP file instead of a normal Java class is [a bad practice in any way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) :)

Comment: Then how to replace those Java calls?, by using JSTL?.